# Shared Element transition between two activities is not appropriate

Tags: java, android, animation

I have an activity which is sharing an Image with the help of shared element transition in Android. But when I click on the Image to launch another activity, it shows odd transition first, and then it shows right transition. Here is the code which calls the adapter:Here is Video To Understand this question better. https://youtu.be/3zPMPC9xsd4

This is the code which is calling the activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostDetails.class);
intent.putExtra("intVariableName", i);
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
        makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context,
                holder.photoHolder,
                "images");
activity.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code

Comment: Ohh Sorry!!! Now I have added it